# TLP vs sysfsutils for limiting machine temperature

Tags: linux, debian, power, temperature, cpu-temperature

Let's say we wish to keep our desktop, which runs Debian stable (with some minor upgrades from snapshots), relatively cool (e.g. because the machine has only passive cooling) by limiting the machine speed.  I see two ways:

1. Install TLP and put

   ```
   CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=powersave
   CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave
   CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=1200000
   CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT=1200000
   ```

   into /etc/tlp.conf or
2. Install sysfsutils and put

   ```
   devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
   ```

   …

   ```
   devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
   devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq = 1200000
   ```

   …

   ```
   devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq = 1200000
   ```

   into /etc/sysfs.conf (our processor has 12 cores).

Which way to go?  Or both?  Or would they get in each other's way?  On the one hand, TLP seems to have additional power-related options (DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC, SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC), and our desktop is similar to a laptop insofar that it often goes into sleep (and wake up from it days later), and the speed limits have to survive sleeps. On the other hand, the documentation of TLP says it's for laptops (whereas the machine in question is a stationary desktop).

Answer (score 0):

On a Debian desktop, TLP and `sysfsutils` can both be used to restrict CPU speed and manage power consumption. TLP may have additional power-saving options that are irrelevant for a desktop because it is specifically made for laptops. Additionally, TLP might replace preferences set using `sysfsutils`, which might result in conflicts.

It may be more appropriate to use `sysfsutils` to set the CPU frequency scaling governor to `powersave` and to set the maximum frequency to 1200000 Hz given your specific requirements for maintaining low CPU temperature on a passive-cooled desktop and enduring sleep modes. By doing this, you can make sure that the CPU is operating at the least amount of power and heat generation. Furthermore, compared to TLP settings, `sysfsutils` configurations typically persist longer through reboots and sleep modes.

It is advised to install `TLP` and utilize its additional power-saving features if they are applicable to your use case in addition to using `sysfsutils` to limit the CPU speed on your Debian desktop.